# Control snackbar transition duration in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, snackbar

Is there a way to control snackbar transition duration?

It seems to be a bit hardcoded in: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/cb9a1d623ccd460c3744ed019af76496c47a353e/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/snack_bar.dart ln: 26

Comment: You can copy the source code locally, modify it, and use an alias to import it

Comment: Considered it but it is pretty hacky